# drop down disappearing on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website with a dropdown menu but when I hover over it, it dissapears. I'm using `margin-top` which is causing this issue but I need to follow a specific design.

Any idea how I can overcome this issue

Here is the website http://techyhesh.com/Dogs/

you will see the issue when you try and hover over the About link and click on a sub-link

HTML

```
<nav role="navigation" id="navmenu">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="page_item page-item-6 current_page_item"><a href="">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-2 page_item_has_children"><a href="">About</a>
                <ul class="children">
                    <li class="page_item page-item-23"><a href="">Everything you need to know</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page_item page-item-25"><a href="">Checklist</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="">Your dog</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-10"><a href="">How can you help your dog</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#navmenu ul ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f4d218;
    margin-top: 1.4em;
    padding: 0 1em 1em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 145px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
#navmenu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#navmenu ul li {
    float: left;
}
#navmenu ul ul li:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}
#navmenu ul ul li {
    border-top: 2px dotted #b58e02;
    margin-top: 1.4em;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#navmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
}
#navmenu li {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#navmenu ul li a {
    color: #706f6f;
    padding: 11px 42px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navmenu {
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #c0d193;
    border-top: 2px dotted #c0d193;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
#navmenu ul ul li a {
    color: #ab8602;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
#navmenu li {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px 0; /*add this*/ 
 }
#navmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#navmenu ul ul {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f4d218;
  top: 100%; /*add this and remove   margin-top: 1.4em;*/
  padding: 0 1em 1em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 145px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

then remove

```
#navmenu {
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #c0d193;
  border-top: 2px dotted #c0d193;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LLtymkrr/2/)

[DEMO FULL](https://jsfiddle.net/LLtymkrr/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: That made not difference, it's still dissapearing when I hover over it

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is disappearing when you try to `:hover` over the ul list is because you have the margin-top of 1.5em on the `#navmenu ul ul`. Get rid of that code and it would work perfectly. But to acheive the effect that you're looking for make these chnages to your CSS:

```
#navmenu ul li a{
  padding: 22px 42px
}

#navmenu ul ul{
  margin-top: 1.1em;
}
```

Comment: I need spacing between the child menu and the nav it's self for design purposes. Is there anyway I can accomplish this without using marin-top?

Answer (score 0):

Your absolute div is too far from its parent element. The gap between the two is causing your dropdown to not work.

You need to either increase the height of the parent link so it is closer to the div, or decrease the margin-top of the div. *(if you increase the height of the parent you have to decrease the margin-top of the div as well)*

```
#navmenu ul ul {
  margin-top: .5em;
}
```